# hivecontext vs spark engine in hive

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

I am new to bigdata. I would like to know the difference between running queries in spark using hivecontext and running queries in hive using spark engine. Which is better and why?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I already checked that answer. But it says spark in hive is better as it has more security than hivecontext. I would like know what these security features are exactly. I would like to tabulate the differences.

Comment: Either way this question is off topic being broad for SO